# R language how to access wts of a class objects nnet

Tags: r

i have built a neural net class object using http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/nnet/nnet and i am trying to access values returned by that object.

Values section of page http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/nnet/nnet says that

"object of class "nnet" or "nnet.formula". Mostly internal structure, but has components wts

the best set of weights found".

But how to get those weights?

i tried below commands but didnt get required results :( any help?

```
    neuralnetobject$wts

    neuralnetobject$finalModel$wts
```

Comment: The `str` command, e.g. `str(neuralnetobject)`, is useful in these situations.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following example from the help file:

```
# use half the iris data
ir <- rbind(iris3[,,1],iris3[,,2],iris3[,,3])
targets <- class.ind( c(rep("s", 50), rep("c", 50), rep("v", 50)) )
samp <- c(sample(1:50,25), sample(51:100,25), sample(101:150,25))
ir1 <- nnet(ir[samp,], targets[samp,], size = 2, rang = 0.1, decay = 5e-4, maxit = 200)
```

to see the wts, I simply typed:

> ir1$wts

```
 [1]   0.21628119   1.00227927   0.69718807   0.29782917   0.05787192
 [6]  -1.16590598  -0.32766698  -0.42501353   0.86931265   1.38749141
[11]  -0.86060194  -0.65800864   1.41229542   2.36515005   2.22664542
[16] -12.65150285 -15.08846194 -14.78377172  33.50059369
```

... to get the resultant wts vector. 
I hope this helps.